# Read word Document using C# Interop and populate it into the DataGrid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, interop

I want to read a Word document using C# Interop and populate it into the DataGrid.
I tried reading Word document by simple console program in c# it worked.

But I'm new to Asp.net and wants to know how to implement the program.
I'm able to create Word document but want to populate it to DATA grid.

```
string filePath = null;
OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();

file.Title = "Word File";
file.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
file.RestoreDirectory = true;

// execute if block when dialog result box click ok button
if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
    // store selected file path
    filePath = file.FileName.ToString();          
}

try
{ 
    // create word application
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass();
    // create object of missing value
    object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    // create object of selected file path
    object path = filePath;
    // set file path mode
    object readOnly = false;
    // open document                
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document docs = word.Documents.Open(ref path, ref miss, ref readOnly, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss,ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);

    docs.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();

    docs.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();

    IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
    //populate data into Datagridview?

    docs.Close(ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? If so, please include it in your question.

Comment: @TomFenech I've included the code above.Now I want the word document contents to be displayed in DATAGRID.How to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using Apache NPOI it has extensive libraries for reading MS Word and other MS Office documents.

http://poi.apache.org/ for JAVA

http://npoi.codeplex.com/ for .Net

Answer (score 0):

Visit these links I think you will find your answer there.

- [Link 1](http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/a25ba73f-324d-4926-93b5-89460f77621d/?Create%20Microsoft%20Word%20Document%20by%20using%20C)
- [Link 2](http://www.dotnetpickles.com/2014/02/aspnet-how-to-read-word-file-in-cnet.html)

Edit:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Read and Display Data From an Word File (.doc or .docx) in ASP.NET</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
                <b>Please Select Excel File: </b>
                <asp:FileUpload ID="fileuploadExcel" runat="server" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:Button ID="btnImport" runat="server" Text="Import Data" OnClick="btnImport_Click" />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Visible="False" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#009933"></asp:Label><br />
                <asp:GridView ID="grvWordData" runat="server">
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#df5015" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="White" />
                </asp:GridView>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now open code behind file and add the following namespaces

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;
```

After that write the following code in code behind

C#.NET Code

```
protected void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string connString = "";
    string strFileType = Path.GetExtension(fileuploadWord.FileName).ToLower();
    string path = fileuploadWord.PostedFile.FileName;

    //Connection String to Word file
    if (strFileType.Trim() == ".doc") {
        connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Word 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
    }
    else if (strFileType.Trim() == ".docx") {
        connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Word 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
    }

    string query = "SELECT * FROM [document1$]";
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        conn.Open();

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    grvWordData.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    grvWordData.DataBind();
    da.Dispose();
    conn.Close();
    conn.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Thanks that helped.But I want to populate the word document to data grid.